# How to "stop" detached thread which is waiting on a condition variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I detach a thread from Class `B`:

```
t1 = std::thread(&Class::method, this);
t1.detach();
```

which as part of it's normal operation waits on a condition variable:

```
cv.wait(lock);
```

However, when I close my B application the detached thread remains. How do I stop/clean-up this thread when `B::~B()` is called?

Comment: @Ron care to enlighten what you do do?

Comment: Why don't you notify the `condition_variable` in the destructor of `B`?

Comment: Why do you think the detached thread outlives your process?

Comment: @Rotem my application is being called within a framework (third party) and when I looked at all threads in GDB, it looked like the previous threads were still active

Comment: @MikevanDyke that's effectively what I thought I should do, but wasn't sure.

Comment: As long as you don't access any members of `B` after `cv.wait(lock)` it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this snippet: Set bool member variable `discard_` to `true` to avoid execution of your scheduled process execution:

```
std::thread([&](){
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
   cv.wait(lock,[](){ return normal_predicate_here || discard_ ;});
   if(discard_) return;
   // execute scheduled process
}).detach();
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the other thread cooperate for termination. Non-detached thread makes it easier to terminate cleanly, so that you do not destroy the state accessed by the other thread prematurely:

```
struct OtherThread {
    std::mutex m_;
    std::condition_variable c_;
    bool stop_ = false;
    std::thread t_;

    void thread_function() {
        for(;;) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m_);
            while(!stop_ /* || a-message-received */)
                c_.wait(l);
            if(stop_)
                return;

            // Process a message.
            // ...
            // Continue waiting for messages or stop.
        }
    }

    ~OtherThread() {
        this->stop();
    }

    void stop() {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m_);
            if(stop_)
                return;
            stop_ = true;
        }
        c_.notify_one();
        t_.join(); // Wait till the thread exited, so that this object can be destroyed.
    }
};
```

Comment: @Caleth It assumes that the thread processes messages in that loop in addition to handling `stop_`.

Comment: You only need *one* loop for that

Comment: So how come @seccpur's answer accomplished it with no loops (well, one hidden away in cv.wait(...))?

Comment: @rubenvb That other answer is different, and also, IMO, error prone.

Comment: It's good practice to _always_ put `wait()` in a loop,.. `while (! condition-you-are-waiting-for) wait();` In some applications and in some environments, the `wait()` call can return when the condition is not true. Even if you can prove that it won't happen in your application and your program's environment, putting the `wait()` call in a loop saves you from having to show the proof to every other programmer who reads your code.

Comment: @james the way I understand it, the "long" call to `std::condition_variable::wait`does exactly that, and also checks the condition-you-are-waiting-for.

Comment: @rubenvb, yes that is a clean way to do it,...  And, it's one that I often forget about, because my background is more Java than C++.